# Lamp Server 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, mysql, apache2, lamp

Hi I just installed ubuntu alongside my Win 7 and I have been using xampp and am very familiar with it, but I just installed lamp and am using the apache2, php, and mysql from terminal and I copied a web folder over from my xampp side and it is saying that I do not have permission to access that file.

I know that on my pc I had some htaccess files but on Ubuntu I am yet to figure out how to view those.  Is this a product of those .htaccess files or something else?

Answer (score 0):

That happens if you install WAMP/XAMMP on system partition.

Comment: is there a way to get around it or am I just outta luck?

Comment: I don't know much about windows but maybe if you run services with an user and give properly rights on xammp folder... could work.

Answer (score 0):

so you copied the files form windows to linux?
sounds like a classic file permissions problem.

per default the www folder is in `/var/www`, so you can simply set the owner of this folder to the apache user which is called `www-data`, run this in terminal:
`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`

but now you will no longer be able to write to those files yourself, because they are owned by www-data. checkout this answer for more details and how to get write access: https://askubuntu.com/a/51337
or you make it writeable for everyone (which is a bad idea): `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www`

---

about editing .htaccess files:

I don't use linux with a graphical user interface, but you can edit them with the terminal editor of your choice, on ubuntu you have `nano` installed by default:
`nano /var/www/.htaccess`

or if you want a more advanced editor, I suggest `vim` https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VimHowto
`vim /var/www/.htaccess`